# regex accepting æøåöô etc

Tags: php, regex, special-characters

Is there an easier regex to filter non-letters (like **%¤#£?|** etc.) from a string, where I want to accept all letters (also special ones like **æøåôöñ** etc.). Do I have to explicitly include every special letter in the regex or is there a smarter way

`$filteredString = preg_replace('/[^a-zæøåÆØÅöôÖÔ 0-9]/i', '', $orgString);`

ps. As you see, I'd like to accept whitespaces as the only non-letter char

pps. Also the caseinsensitive "i" does not seem to apply with special letters

Comment: So what exactly *do* you accept and *don't* you accept? There are several hundred thousand "letter" and "non-letter" characters possible, you know?

Comment: true - and I'd like to accept all the "letters" and filter out all "non-letters" like quotes, dots, dashes etc.. Currently I use this expression '/[^a-zæøåÆØÅäëöÿïüÄËÏÖÜñÑãÃâîûôêÂÎÔÛÊµ 0-9]/i', but thats missing quite alot of letters... Actually all letters used for writing words in any language is what I would like to accept - in a simple regex-statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/[^\w\s\pL]/u
```

See [php regex](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php). These are all word characters, whitespace and Unicode letters. The trailing `u` indicates Unicode handling.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\w` for word character (includes underscore as well), also better to use `u` modifier for unicode characters:

```
/[^\w\sæøåÆØÅöôÖÔ]/iu
```